# Set column order based on observations in a row

Tags: r, data.table

I have data similar to this:

```
  set.seed(1)
  dt <- data.table(stock = c(rep("a",24),rep("b",24),rep("c",24),rep("d",24)),
  hour = rep(1:24,4), day1 = sample(-5:5,96,replace = TRUE), 
  day2 = sample(-10:-1,96,replace = TRUE), day3 = sample(0:10,96,replace = TRUE),
  day4 = 0)
```

I create a column totaling each day and I create a row totaling all stock for each day as follows:

```
  dt[,Total_by_hour := rowSums(.SD), .SDcols = c("day1","day2","day3","day4")] 
  totals_row <- data.table(stock = "Total",hour = NA, t(colSums(dt[,!1:2])))
  dt <- rbind(dt,totals_row)
```

Which looks like:

```
  stock hour    day1    day2    day3    day4    Total_by_hour
  a      1      -3       -6      1       0      -8
  a      2      -1       -6      10      0      3
  a      3       1       -2      3       0      2
  ...                   
  d      22      4       -5      1       0      0
  d      23      3       -3      3       0      3
  d      24      3       -7      1       0      -3
  Total         18       -507    426     0      -63
```

I would like to sort the rows descending by the "Total_by_hour" column.  I would also like to set the column order of just the day1,day2,day3,day4 columns descending ordered based on the last row "Total", ie. reordered to day3 (Total of 426), day1 (Total of 18), day4 (Total of 0), day2 (Total of -507).

I welcome any ideas. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reorder the rows of a data.table with the `setorder` function and order the columns with the `setcolorder` function:

```
# Order by Total_by_hour descending 
setorder(dt, -Total_by_hour)
```

Output:

```
> head(dt)
   stock hour day1 day2 day3 day4 Total_by_hour
1:     a   21    5   -3    8    0            10
2:     c   20    3   -3   10    0            10
3:     d    4    4   -2    8    0            10
4:     a    8    2   -1    8    0             9
5:     a   15    3   -1    6    0             8
6:     d    5    4   -2    6    0             8
```

And then to reorder the day columns:

```
# Create a vector of the column names to reorder
cols_to_order <- paste0("day", 1:4)

# Get the order of the Total row for just these columns
reorder <- rev(order(dt[stock == "Total", cols_to_order, with = F]))

# Set the new column order
setcolorder(dt, neworder = c("stock", "hour", cols_to_order[reorder], "Total_by_hour"))
```

Output:

```
> head(dt)
   stock hour day3 day1 day4 day2 Total_by_hour
1:     a   21    8    5    0   -3            10
2:     c   20   10    3    0   -3            10
3:     d    4    8    4    0   -2            10
4:     a    8    8    2    0   -1             9
5:     a   15    6    3    0   -1             8
6:     d    5    6    4    0   -2             8
```

Comment: Thanks @efbbrown.  This is just what I needed!  Laying it out step by step makes the code very readable.

Answer (score 2):

Another way using data.table

```
library(data.table)
setorder( dt, Total_by_hour)
setcolorder( dt, c(grep("day", colnames(dt), value = TRUE, invert = TRUE),
                   colnames( sort(dt[ nrow(dt), .SD, .SDcols = grep("day", colnames(dt)) ], decreasing = TRUE))))

head(dt)
#    stock hour Total_by_hour day3 day1 day4 day2
# 1: Total   NA           -63  426   18    0 -507
# 2:     a   10           -11    2   -5    0   -8
# 3:     d   14           -11    1   -3    0   -9
# 4:     b   23            -9    4   -5    0   -8
# 5:     c   16            -9    1   -2    0   -8
# 6:     c   23            -9    3   -2    0  -10
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution @Sathish.  This works perfectly too.

Answer (score 1):

using dplyr:
First, arrange by the last column.

```
library(dplyr)
dt_1 <- dt %>% arrange(Total_by_hour)
```

Now, calculate the total and sort the columns accordingly

```
dt_cols <- dt %>% select(contains("day")) %>% summarise_all(sum)
rank(dt_cols[1,])
columns_ordered <- c("stock", "hour", 
                     c("day1","day2","day3","day4")[rank(dt_cols[1,])],
                     "Total_by_hour")
dt_2 <- dt_1[ , columns_ordered]
```

Finally, add the "total" row again:

```
totals_row <- data.table(stock = "Total",hour = NA, t(colSums(dt_2[,3:7])))
dt_2 <- rbind(dt_2,totals_row)
```

Comment: Thanks @Sastibe.  This works great for those who want to use dplyr.